# Has anyone used AI to design airplanes?

Tags: aircraft-design, artificial-intelligence

Photo example

Prototype drawings

Any response from someone who has done it.

Comment: Would you mind using complete sentences in your question?  A list of bullet points is fine when introduced with something that a grade-school teacher would recognize as a sentence: a subject, a verb, appropriate punctuation, etc.  As it stands, this question asks for quite a bit of information in response, but shows the very slightest possible effort at presenting what it is you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

AI is an extremely broad definition encompassing hundreds (literally!) of methodologies.

For sure some of them have been used in the aerospace world: genetic algorithms, Fuzzy logic, speech recognition, decision tree, image recognition, optimisation algorithms...

If you follow [this advice](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/95521/has-anyone-used-ai-to-design-airplanes#comment263255_95521) maybe we can narrow down the scope and give one more precise and useful answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63268)

Comment: The question is if "Has anyone used AI to design airplanes" My answer is yes and I gave some examples. Plus, I'd be glad to give a more specific answer if requested. Why that shouldn't answer the question?

Answer (score -1):

Aviation Youtuber Bryan Turner has done exactly this.

Comment: -1  What happens to your answer when/if this video is removed from YouTube?